# Calculating the total value of each column in GridView and Displaying them in Footer

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have 7 columns in my Gridview starting from Sunday to Saturday. I need to add the values within each column and display them on footer. 
I tried doing for single column but not able to do for each column.

```
   int total=0;
    protected void gvEmployeeTimeSheet_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {          

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {  
            Label lblsaturday = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblSaturday");
            int qty = Int32.Parse(lblsaturday.Text);
             total = total + qty;
        }

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            Label lblTotalqty = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblFootersaturday");
            lblTotalqty.Text = total.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not do the same thing for other columns?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is before binding your dataset to your GridView calculate the totals and insert a new record to your dataset. Then you don't need to loop through your GridView once it's bound.